# Axios IF statement will not return error when param is invalid

Tags: node.js, axios

When a GET request is sent through Postman with a valid city, the `res.json(data);` works fine. However, if the city is invalid, I am getting the 500 response, and not the 404 with the message that I expect. Why isn't the IF statement catching that?

```
router.get('/:city', (req, res) => {
    const city = req.params.city;
    const url = `${process.env.BASEURL}${city}&units=imperial&APPID=${process.env.API_KEY}`;

    axios.get(url)
        .then(response => { 
            const data = response.data;
            if(data.errors && data.errors.length > 0) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    message: 'City not found'
                });
            }
            res.json(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                message: error.message
            })
        });
});
```

EDIT:

It turns out that when I request an invalid city, the api responds with:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Request failed with status code 404"
}
```

I thought that this meant that I needed to change `if(data.errors && data.errors.length > 0)` to `if(data.success == true)`. However, I am still getting the 500 response and not the 404 that I want.

EDIT 2:

So, I decided to just ditch `axios` and use `node-fetch` instead. I am getting the 404 I have been wanting! I have no idea what's been going on with axios, so if anyone figures it out, I'd love to know. Here's my new code:

```
router.get('/:city', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const city = req.params.city;
        const url = `${process.env.BASEURL}${city}&units=imperial&APPID=${process.env.API_KEY}`;

        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();

        if(data.cod == '404') {
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: data.message
            });
        }
        res.json(data);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Server error'
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: whats the result of axios.get(url) ? maybe if its status code isnt 200, it fails to catch block

Comment: I'm getting a 200 status on the fetch request, just not the 404

Comment: so once again whats inside of response variable ?

Comment: How would I check that? I tried `console.log(axios.get(url))`, but it expects a promise and won't run.

Comment: try in your postman the exact same url as you put to the axios to see the results from it ... the result status code will be the key to the bug fix and also the url doesnt seem valid since BASEURL is not like url/endpoint?city=ciryParam&units=imp... if i am wrong i am sorry, but without the url value i cant say more

Comment: BASEURL:   https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=

Comment: I also updated my original post